# Is it possible to fire event on jquery tabs plugin when we switch tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use jquery tabs plugin, but can't figure out how to set the event when user switches between tabs.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the [`activate()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate) event.

```
$(".selector").tabs({
    activate: function(event, ui) {
        alert("You changed tabs");
        // Or do something more constructive...
    }
});
```

Comment: I am trying to use this method: $("#tabs").on("tabsactivate", function (event, ui) { alert('qwer'); }); But it doesn't work. Event just doesn't fire

Answer (score 1):

```
activate( event, ui )
```

Triggered after a tab has been activated (after animation completes). If the tabs were previously collapsed, ui.oldTab and ui.oldPanel will be empty jQuery objects. If the tabs are collapsing, ui.newTab and ui.newPanel will be empty jQuery objects.

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
    activate: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Bind an event listener to the tabsactivate event:

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "tabsactivate", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

Comment: I am trying to use this method:
$("#tabs").on("tabsactivate", function (event, ui) { alert('qwer'); }); But it doesn't work. Event just doesn't fire